# How can I make shutdown not require admin password?

Tags: administration, shutdown

If more than one person is logged in on my computer, Ubuntu requires super user authentication when shutting down the computer. How can I make it so that any user can shutdown the computer without being asked for a password?

Comment: +1 I suspect entering a password to shutdown annoys many users on a home based PC.

Comment: If you shut down a computer while others are logged in, what happens to their open windows? Their open documents? I think anything that doesn't autosave is simply lost. This is worth considering.

Comment: "Ubuntu requires super user authentication when shutting down the computer", in Ubuntu 11.10 it doesn't ask for superuser authorisation, when shutdown using menu, it only works as logout and brings to Login page, like in this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/64073/11995, i'm interested how to configure Ubuntu to ask me for a superuser password?

Comment: **For 14.04 and later:** see http://askubuntu.com/questions/454039/what-command-is-executed-when-shutdown-from-the-graphical-menu-in-14-04

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**You do not need a workaround, just change the policy to allow you to shut down without authenticating as admin for shutdown and reboot when multiple users are logged in.**

Edit the file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.consolekit.policy using your favorite text editor. You will need root permissions.

Change the section relating to shutdown when others are logged in from

```xml
  <action id="org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users">
    <description>Stop the system when multiple users are logged in</description>
    <message>System policy prevents stopping the system when other users are logged in</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

to

```xml
  <action id="org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users">
    <description>Stop the system when multiple users are logged in</description>
    <message>System policy prevents stopping the system when other users are logged in</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

and the section relating to rebooting when others are logged in from

```xml
  <action id="org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart-multiple-users">
    <description>Restart the system when multiple users are logged in</description>
    <message>System policy prevents restarting the system when other users are logged in</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

to

```xml
  <action id="org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart-multiple-users">
    <description>Restart the system when multiple users are logged in</description>
    <message>System policy prevents restarting the system when other users are logged in</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
```

And that will allow you shutdown and reboot the PC when multiple users are logged in.
Whether you want to do that is a different question.

Comment: Here is a link with more on policykit : http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/PolicyKit/polkit-conf.html

Comment: This is to address being asked a password when shutting down the system from with Gnome.

Comment: Won't your changes be wiped out whenever polkit is reinstalled or upgraded?

Comment: Um holy crap that is awesome. I had no idea about PolicyKit.

Comment: @Ryan, that all depends how it is packaged. I personally have no idea but I suspect you are right.

Comment: Whenever I need to modify a file that belongs to a package, I use apt-src to get the source for it, and then I make the change in the source, then I compile it and the resulting package has my desired changes.

Comment: @Ryan, according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PolicyKitPermissions/12.04 you could write a .pkla file inside /etc/polkit-1/localauthority, but I'm not sure about its syntax :) (some info here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PolicyKit#Authorities)

Comment: Answer below from Flimm is better, won't get written over during an update

http://askubuntu.com/a/251942/7472

Comment: How to reload rules without reboot?

Answer (score 40):

[Richard Holloway's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1399/2355) is not actually the way PolickKit authorisations are meant to be granted. The files installed under `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` are not meant to be modified. Instead, you should modify the authorities under `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`.

Here's how you do it for this question:

Create a file named `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/allow_all_users_to_shutdown.pkla` and edit it using `sudoedit` to look like this:

```
[Allow all users to shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Then create another `.pkla` file in the same directory. Use any name you like ending with `.pkla`, for example, `allow_all_users_to_restart.pkla`, and fill it with these contents:

```
[Allow all users to restart]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart-multiple-users
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

#### References:

- [polkit Reference Manual: pklocalauthority](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html)
- [ArchWiki page on PolicyKit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PolicyKit)

Comment: This turned out to be the solution for a very odd problem. On 12.04 after installing PowerBroker (to authenticate to Active Directory), users could not restart or shutdown a computer at all with the GUI (neither lightdm nor indicator-session worked. It would just return to the login screen.) After adding these permissions to policykit, everything worked.

Comment: man pklocalauthority has the info in Ubuntu

Comment: Note that the names has changed now! This is from 14.04:

/usr/share/polkit-1/actions$ grep multiple  *
org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions">
org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions">
org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions">
org.freedesktop.login1.policy:        <action id="org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions">

Comment: For 16.04, in addition to @Konstigt's changes, for me the files had to be in `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` and the additional line `ResultAny=yes` was necessary for both files. The only warning message I now get is `Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.`, but shutting down and restarting works correctly now.

Comment: @sigalor's comment worked for me, with the addition that `sysctl poweroff -i` requires `org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions`, so I made a separate file with the same lines except with `Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions`

Answer (score 16):

There is a better way. If you have dbus-send installed, you can shutdown via dbus **without the need to escalate to root privileges**.

I can't remember the page where the documentation is, but one Archlinux user figured this out.

*Shutdown:*

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```

*Reboot:*

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Reboot
```

*Suspend:*

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Suspend int32:1
```

*Hibernate:*

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
          /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
          org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Hibernate
```

Regards.

Comment: Wow that is... hacky. Awesome, yet hacky...

Comment: Shutdown and Reboot seems doesn't work anymore in 11.10

Comment: @Mikl try install hal (sudo apt-get install hal)

Answer (score 12):

HAL seems to be now depcrecated and not installed in latest Ubuntu releases.

You must use [ConsoleKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit) and [UPower](http://upower.freedesktop.org/) dbus services to manage power state

Shutdown:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

Restart:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

Suspend:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

Hibernate:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

Thanks to Arch Linux [forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127962).

This works for now in Precise and Quantal, but don't know for how long since the Freedesktop focus seems to be shifted from ConsoleKit to systemd. Don't know whether Canonical cares...

Answer (score 10):

This works on 14.04. An updated variation of the previous, IMO, correct [answer by Flimm](https://askubuntu.com/a/251942/7472).

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d
sudoedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/allow_all_users_to_shutdown_reboot_suspend.pkla
```

Paste this inside:

```
[Allow all users to shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to reboot]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to ignore inhibit of shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to ignore inhibit of reboot]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to ignore inhibit of suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: I had to replace `ResultActive` with `ResultAny` on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I also had to add blocks for `Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off`, `Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot`, and `Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to circumvent the prompt for a superuser password when rebooting while other users are logged in short of opening a terminal window and issuing the `reboot` command as root:

```
sudo reboot
```

Even still, if not configured to bypass password prompting for your user account, `sudo` will also prompt you for your password.

Don't worry, these are GOOD things.  Rebooting should be rare and a simple admin password prompt saves accidentally hosing yourself!

Comment: You can also edit visudo and make your user not prompt for password when typing sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is only an issue when doing it through the command line.

If so here is a [link](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/315/how-to-shutdown-and-reboot-without-sudo-password/) that can help with your problem.

Comment: No, there is a popup window that asks for the admin password if there is another user logged in when you shut it down. Using the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Add halt and/or reboot into sudoers file assigned to the group/user you wish to allow to perform this task. That way you can still control who can shutdown, but without giving them full root access to the machine..

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/315/how-to-shutdown-and-reboot-without-sudo-password/

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, you are able to shut down without root from the GUI because gdm runs as root. Gnome tells gdm to shut down, and gdm does it.

You could do something similar with a script. I'm not sure how handy you are with BASH, but I believe one could write a script that runs as root and, when it receives a certain signal, runs the shutdown command.

Keep in mind that this may pose a security problem.

Comment: I think the problem he's likely to be encountering is the prompt that appears advising that others are still logged in, and requiring a sudo password to enable the shut-down/restart.