# Shutdown and Reboot is causing Logout, and brings me to Login page

Tags: 11.10, shutdown

While I am trying to Reboot or Shutdown my system using the menu, I am again routed to Login page. From the login page I am not able to shutdown or reboot the system, only thing i can do is to login.

Comment: what happens if you try: `sudo reboot` or `sudo poweroff` ?

Comment: "sudo shutdown -h now" works fine

Comment: exactly the same symptoms: http://askubuntu.com/q/64073/11995, except that i have not logged by myself using a few users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freevo was the trouble maker. I uninstall Freevo and shutdown works fine.

Occasionally, i press CTRL+ALT+F9 and found Freevo, it was starting automatically on boot.
I press exit and Freevo closed. After this i go to previos default tty (CTRL+ALT+F7), and then shutdown Ubuntu successfully.
This i have found in logs:

```
/var/log/auth.log.1:503:Dec 18 01:33:34 m-desktop su[1069]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user freevo
```

I think that i was unable to shutdown, because of another user "freevo", which was logged in automatically on boot.