# Why can ubuntu perform a shutdown from the GUI even though it is prive on the command line?

Tags: gnome, shutdown, unprivileged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between menu shutdown and 'shutdown -h now'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86355/difference-between-menu-shutdown-and-shutdown-h-now)

Why can ubuntu perform a shutdown from the GUI even though it is prive on the command line?
By what mechanism does it do so?

Comment: ^Not a duplicate, read that already.

Comment: @awiebe Can you please edit your question to make more sense? I am finding it hard to understand how this is not a duplicate?

Comment: IMO, awebie asked about the mechanism that allows doing the shutdown without root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism seems to be a DBus message, sent to a process with root privileges. Taken from [How can I make shutdown not require admin password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password/1367#1367):

> *Shutdown:*
>
> ```
> dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal \
>           /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
>           org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
> ```