# My Ubuntu system doesn't shutdown. Stays in splash screen

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, xubuntu, shutdown, xfce

I updated from Ubuntu 11.10, I had installed also XFCE on that version but mainly used Unity, after I upgraded to 12.04 when I shutdown it doesn't shutdown it remains in a XUbuntu splash screeen. I mention that I did't installed, XUbuntu but probably installing XFCE installed also that splash screen.

How can I fix that and make the system shutdown without using hard shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo shutdown -h now` in the terminal window.

Comment: Somehow this fixed also the Shutdown from Unity that I use more often than the command line and now it doesn't halt in the above described splash screen.

Comment: You might also want to check out http://askubuntu.com/a/202112/90933