# what is the right way to shutdown ubuntu using the command line?

Tags: shutdown, command-line

I know that there are several commands that shutdown an Ubuntu computer. I was just wondering if there is a right one to use and what the implications are for using the other ones; or what the various scenarios are for using each of the available commands and their parameters.

Comment: for shutdown without administrator password see [our Q&A on the dbus way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The right way to shutdown Ubuntu using the CLI(Command Line Interface) is `sudo shutdown now`.

Comment: Wow! That was fast!. Just saw a similar question and was about to delete this one

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04 system, this doesn't work. The command completes, but no shutdown is initiated. Adding `-h` doesn't change this.

Answer (score 9):

You can shutdown safely running:

```
sudo poweroff
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using shut down preceded with sync - probably old school but it commits unwritten data to disk - especially useful in multiuser systems. [Linux System Administrators Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/shutdown.html)