# Why does `reboot` and `poweroff` work without super user privileges in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: suspend, shutdown, root, reboot

There  are a lot of questions about why `shutdown` and `reboot` require root privileges. There are many good answers available too.

- [**Why do we need to be root in terminal for shutdown and restart?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361988/why-do-we-need-to-be-root-in-terminal-for-shutdown-and-restart)
- [**Why does reboot and poweroff require root privileges?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253767/why-does-reboot-and-poweroff-require-root-privileges)
- [**How does the power button shut the computer down without root permission?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18503/how-does-the-power-button-shut-the-computer-down-without-root-permission)

**But there is someting I don't understand** : If being able to reboot or shutdown without root privileges in a *multiuser* system is a **very bad** idea ... then why is this possible in Ubuntu 16.04?

When I type `poweroff` or `reboot` in a terminal and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it indeed shuts down/reboots!

It is okay for me when `poweroff` and `reboot` don't require root privileges ... but why does `suspend` need root privileges? 
 When I type `suspend` in a terminal and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it doesn't suspend, instead it gets stuck ... and when I run `pm-suspend`, It requires `sudo`.

Comment: This should be possible in older versions as well, if you configure it do so (http://askubuntu.com/a/570969/158442, note the actions for mutliple sessions). Systemd does this by default though. Also seen on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, both `poweroff` nor `reboot` needs a password on Ubuntu 16.04 .

However, for this to occur, I had to create a user account called "foo", for example, and then ssh to localhost as either that user or as myself.  When I do this, I do need to authenticate myself.  It seems to recognize another user is logged in.

For example, I get this message:

```
User foo is logged in on sshd.
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl reboot -i'.
```

Presumably, it's "smart" enough to realize when there is in fact another user logged in.

(I agree with you that it would be nice to always authenticate as root.  Sometimes, no other user is logged in, but an important process is running in background performing some kind of calculation.)

Edit:  Just tried myself.  If I'm logged in as foo, I need to authenticate myself (who is in the sudo group).  If I reboot as myself with foo still logged in, I have to type `systemctl reboot -i` without a password.  I presume the difference is that the system knows I'm in the sudo group.

Edit 2:  As noted by Severus Tux, `systemctl suspend -i` behaved similar to `systemctl reboot -i` from the previous edit.

Comment: Ah.. I had not tried that. BTW does suspend command work on your machine ? I need to make sure that its a bug

Comment: If I ssh to localhost and suspend, I am unsuccessful.  I get "-bash: suspend: cannot suspend a login shell".

Comment: If I open a window and try "suspend", the terminal window freezes.  :-)  Not a good sign...  I think that's unrelated.  Anyway, thanks for asking!  I never thought of trying myself but your question made me curious.  I'm still in the habit of rebooting with sudo...didn't notice this subtle change.

Comment: Thank you. As you said about reboot,  "systemctl suspend -i" also works well. consider adding that to your answer

Comment: Ok!  I probably should have added it all with one message, but each time I tried something, it caused a reboot, so I had to save what I was posting...