# How do I disable need to authentication when an app asked for inhibit of shutdown / suspend

Tags: shutdown, suspend

I would like to disable so I never get this popup. And also I would like to know what application has asked for it, so maybe I can stop it. Does anyone know?

[image: Authenticate]

Edit: A solution can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/486425/7472

Comment: I've never seen this, what are the Details? At which time did you get this popup, what are you doing before this? Is this related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password ?

Comment: It very well could be, I will try this. The setup is multi-user. There also is a bug involved in this and that is if you do suspend, nothing happens and nothing is reported to the user. It is only if I do shutdown that I get this popup.

Comment: Yes, that question above works as a solution to the original problem.