# How do I avoid shutdown-inhibition caused by an interrupted, then completed, Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, suspend, reboot, authentication

When I try to suspend/reboot my Ubuntu 18.04, I get  a dialog asking for a password:

```
"Authentication is required for suspending [respectively: rebooting] the system
while an application asked to inhibit it"
```

How do I avoid this?

[This answer actually works for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password/486425#486425). But that question involved shutdown-inhibition due to multiple users. In my case, the cause is an interrupted, then successfully completed, Ubuntu upgrade from 17.10. So there is probably some lock file, and ignoring lock files is dangerous, so I would like to understand what is happening first.

Data

1. (Here is [one minute from  my syslog](https://pastebin.com/ezacz2Es). As seen there, I started the suspend process at 18:19:00, was asked and then gave the password. The laptop was suspended, and then I resumed it.)
2. `lslocks` shows dozens of ordinary application locks from Eclipse, Slack, Chrome, Firefox, Atom, and KeePassX. Other than that, there are these lines. Maybe the `dpkg` lock means something?

`COMMAND           PID   TYPE  SIZE MODE  M      START        END PATH`

`lvmetad           322  POSIX       WRITE 0          0          0 /run...`

`thermald          817  POSIX       WRITE 0          0          0 /run...`

`cron              863  FLOCK       WRITE 0          0          0 /run...`

`dpkg            24505  POSIX       WRITE 0          0          0 /...`

`whoopsie         1651  FLOCK       WRITE 0          0          0 /run/lock...`

3. The command  `sudo lsof |grep dpkg` [shows this.](https://pastebin.com/TmYp7mfy)

Comment: ckeck syslog near the date of shutdown and paste more info

Comment: OK, I added it to the body

Comment: @cmak.fr I also found a solution that resolves the immediate problem, but seems dangerous . See the edited body .

Comment: list locks : `lslocks`

Comment: 1st you can disable whoopsie. 2nd, find files locked by dpkg with `sudo lsof | grep dpkg`

Comment: Thanks, I disabled whoopsie. I added the  sudo lsof |grep dpkg  in the  body (also https://pastebin.com/TmYp7mfy )

Comment: try this `sudo killall dpkg; sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo sudo dpkg --configure -a` -- If it doesnt work, try harder `sudo killall dpkg; sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock; sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; sudo sudo dpkg --configure -a`