# How do I avoid shutdown/restart authentication caused by application inhibition in my Ubuntu 18.04 system?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, authentication, linux-headers, droidcam

When I am trying to restart/shutdown my Ubuntu 18.04, it requires authentication, showing dialog box with message:

> "Authentication is required for rebooting/powering_off the system
>   while an application asked to inhibit it"

Is there any way to clear off application inhibition?

**History**:
I was trying to install droidcam in ubuntu 18.04, but it turned out no device driver was installed "/dev/video[0-9]", according to [solution](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/59#issuecomment-46037985) I tried "sudo apt-get install linux-generic" and I *killed the process* in between,in the terminal. I don't know exactly how to get off this, can anyone help me?

Sources I referred: [source1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133007/droidcam-installation-error-on-ubuntu-18-04) [source2](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=49702)

Similar question: [ques1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049463/how-do-i-avoid-shutdown-inhibition-caused-by-an-interrupted-then-completed-ubu)

(**note**: I am a beginner to linux)