# systemctl asking for password

Tags: ssh, suspend, password

I'm trying to get the machine to go to sleep with systemctl suspend, however every time I try to do this over an SSH session it asks for the password twice, one to set a wall message and another to actually suspend the system
If I run this command directly from the system terminal it does not require any authentication
Login in SSH is done with the same user that I use in the system

Is this something I need to configure in sudoers? Anything I need to change?

Comment: Maybe run `sudo systemctl suspend` instead of `systemctl suspend`

Comment: Probably related [How can I make shutdown not require admin password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password) (but in this case it's possibly the `allow_inactive` field that needs to be modified)

Comment: Running with sudo still asks for a password, I do not need any authentication when running the command directly on the terminal

Comment: Offered solution points to a file not present on 18.04

Comment: @MarioGomez but not two, right?

Comment: @muru Yes, but the idea is no prompts for password

Comment: Sure, but the process for setting no password rules for sudoers is well documented and hasn't changed